# Storage Representation and Required Space for Variant Records in Pascal

Tags: memory-management, record, pascal

I try to use a variant record as the following statements show:

```
Type paytype=(salaried, hourly);
Var employee: record
Id: integer;
Dept: array [1...3] of char;
Age: integer;
Case payclass: paytype of
Salaried (monthlyrate: real; stardate: integer);
Hourly (hourrate: real; reg: integer; stardate: integer);
Hourly (hourrate: real; reg: integer; overtime: integer);
```

Now, i am considering the space it will be using then. i try to draw a memory representation for it in the below picture.

[image]

i assume that Integer:2 Bytes, Real:6 Bytes, Char:1 Byte.

- what will be the total amount of needed space? will it be 17 Bytes or 18 Bytes?
- what is the size of memory dedicated to the tag (Payclass)?

Comment: Start with changing your code, so that it will compile without errors! Then use the sizeof function to answer your questions.

Comment: Also note that the size may depend on alignment settings for your compiler, although old Pascal versions (e.g. those with 16 bit integers) generally used no alignment at all, i.e. all records were byte.packed. And the size of PayClass may depend on compiler settings too: either smallest required to hold the bits, or a fixed size. So do what @gammatester said.

Comment: PayClass will be the size of it's largest alternative (in this case, Hourly). You can get the overall record size using `sizeof`.

Comment: @Ken: not really. Payclass (the enumeration) will be the size that can contain all bit values, or it is fixed (e.g. in Delphi, probably FreePascal too). Did you mean the record size?

Comment: @In a book, for the solution of above problem,it states the whole record will get 18 Bytes of memory? does it mean the solution get the tag 1 Byte ? @ Rudy Velthuis

Comment: @Rudy: No, I meant *the portion of the record accessed by the PayClass enumeration*.

Comment: @user3187561: the size of the record depends on compiler settings for alignment and enum size. So the record will be at least 18 bytes in size, but it can also be larger. The tag could be one byte or larger.

Comment: @KenWhite: Ok understood, although that was not clear from what you wrote.